# Echo data into two files

Tags: shell

How do I insert data into files at a time?

Consider if I have like data below:

```
echo "hi" >> file1
echo "hi" >> file2
```

How can I redirect the same "hi" into file1 and file2 simultaneously?

Answer (score 12):

```
$ echo hi | tee -a file1 file2
```

See [the `tee` manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee).

Comment: You are missing the `-a` option to match the example.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the `>>`.

Comment: You can also use `-a` multiple times if there are more than 2 target files.